# Upload volume changes do not apply to php.ini

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, update, file-upload, profile

Hi I have a centos 7 server and a cwp 7 panel. I have the latest version of Joomla and WordPress installed on them. The size of uploaded files in Joomla is 2 MB. I increased the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size sizes through the php section of the cwp 7 panel. Unfortunately this extension did not apply to Joomla! I also restarted Apache but it did not change. I even changed the php.ini file manually, but this did not work in Joomla. (It is interesting that this increase is applied correctly in WordPress and there is no problem)
I did everything I could to increase the upload volume in Joomla, but the file size of the media section and the installation section of the Joomla plugin did not change!
please guide me

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support/feedback.